# Objective-c/iOS: setting status text in async function is slow

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

In my app I'm doing some communication with a remote server and as this might be slow I thought it would be a good idea to run that code asynchronously. I have my communication code in a block that I pass to dispatch_async. This code does the communication and when it's done it sets the text of a label. This last part is the problem. The text is set, but it occurs after a delay of a few seconds. This is my code.

```
- (void)doNetworkingTask {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // Slow network task goes here.

        // Slow network task done, notify the user.
        [self.myLabel setText:@"task done."];
        NSLog(@"task done.");
    });
}
```

What happens here is that my network task completes, the NSLog-text is logged and after a couple of seconds, the text of the label is updated. My question is 1) why does the label text not update instantly? and 2) what is a proper way of doing what I want to do? (do the slow network task without blocking anything else, update the user through a text label once I'm done.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UI updates must be on the main thread. Update your code to something like this:

```
- (void)doNetworkingTask {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // Slow network task goes here.

        // Slow network task done, notify the user.
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.myLabel setText:@"task done."];
        });
        NSLog(@"task done.");
    });
}
```

Comment: That solved my problem :). On a side note, is this a good way of doing what I want to do or is there some better way to perform slow tasks without blocking the rest of the app?

Comment: This is exactly what should be done. Run long running tasks in a background queue. All UI updates must be done on the main queue.